# Analizing MIPS binaries: is there a Python library for parsing binary data?

Tags: python, x86, mips, elf, dwarf

I'm working on a utility which needs to resolve hex addresses to a symbolic function name and source code line number within a binary. The utility will run on Linux on x86, though the binaries it analyzes will be for a MIPS-based embedded system. The MIPS binaries are in ELF format, using DWARF for the symbolic debugging information.

I'm currently planning to fork objdump, passing in a list of hex addresses and parsing the output to get function names and source line numbers. I have compiled an objdump with support for MIPS binaries, and it is working.

I'd prefer to have a package allowing me to look things up natively from the Python code without forking another process. I can find no mention of libdwarf, libelf, or libbfd on python.org, nor any mention of python on dwarfstd.org.

Is there a suitable module available somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check [pyelftools](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools) - a new pure Python library meant to do this.

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in the DWARF library from [pydevtools](http://code.google.com/p/pydevtools/):

```
>>> from bintools.dwarf import DWARF
>>> dwarf = DWARF('test/test')
>>> dwarf.get_loc_by_addr(0x8048475)
('/home/emilmont/Workspace/dbg/test/main.c', 36, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should give [Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/) a try. It is very useful to parse binary data into python objects.

There is even an example for the [ELF32](http://sebulbasvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/construct/formats/executable/elf32.py) file format.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar and checked out Construct. What's there is quite nice, but the project hasn't been updated in quite some time.

Comment: Just had a look at Construct, and it seems really terrific. Very impressed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any, but if all else fails you could use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-ctypes.html) to directly use libdwarf, libelf or libbfd.

Answer (score 3):

I've been developing a DWARF parser using [Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/). Currently fairly rough, and parsing is slow. But I thought I should at least let you know. It may suit your needs, with a bit of work.

I've got the code in Mercurial, hosted at bitbucket:

- http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/pythondwarf/
- http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/construct/ (necessary modifications to Construct library)

[Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/) is a very interesting library. DWARF is a complex format (as I'm discovering) and pushes Construct to its limits I think.

Comment: Hi Craig, do you have any examples of how to use your DWARF parser? I've looked at your repo but couldn't find any. How could I do something like emilmont's dwarf.get_loc_by_addr() example?

Comment: @NickToumpelis, I haven't done any more work on this for a while, but I'm now just getting back to it since it could be useful at my work. I'm not entirely happy with the Construct-based solution, because it's slow to do the parsing. So, there's currently no high-level API as you requested. It gets as far as parsing the DWARF info into a tree. The next task would be to search the tree for the info you're looking for. DWARF format is so expressive, I'm not sure what would be a good simple API to access the data.

Comment: Craig: pyelftools (https://bitbucket.org/eliben/pyelftools) is built on top of `construct`, using it for the low-level API, but adding a feature-full high-level API on top

Answer (score 2):

[hachior](http://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home) is another library for parsing binary data