# Trying to compile libdwarf, gives undefined errors

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, dwarf

I'm trying to build the libdwarf api under windows but I'm receiving the following compile errors.

```
in dwarf_elf_access.c
undefined type Elf32_Ehdr,
undefined symbol EI_CLASS
undefined symbol ELFCLASS64
undefined symbol ELFDATA2LSB
...
```

I did a search through all the header files and source files and I couldn't find them defined anywhere as far as I could tell. Are these unix/linux specific definitions? If it is how should these errors be resolved under windows?

Thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using? I assumed gcc in my answer.

Comment: @terminus thanks for responding. The compiler I'm using is borland/embar but I get the same issue when compiling with MSVC9

Comment: Corrected it to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to link the libelf library too (the dwarf library uses it).

Answer (score 3):

Terminus is right, libdwarf depends on the libelf library.

I successfully compiled this one with msvc2008 and 2010.
http://directory.fsf.org/project/libelf/

Comment: Thank you, after some googling I came up with the same link. Will post an update on here if I run into further issues.

Comment: +1 thanks for the link to that libelf.   From my research it seems to be the only libelf implementation with a windows build right out of the box.  Additionally, my sample elf producing test program works perfectly with that libelf on windows, while using an adapted version of the elftoolchain libelf produces corrupted elf files on occasion.