# How can I obtain a PE file's instructions using Python?

Tags: python, portable-executable, capstone

So I'm trying to write a basic disassembler for a school project using Python.  I'm using the pydasm and capstone libraries.  What I don't understand is how I can actually access the assembly instructions of a program using Python.  These libraries allow me to disassemble instructions, but I can't figure out how to access a program's instructions in Python.  Could anyone give me some direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should be cautious about the code section as the base of the code section might not contain only code (imports or read only data might be present at this location).

The best way to start a disassembly is by looking at the `AddressOfEntryPoint` field in the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` which indicates the first executed byte in the PE file (except if TLS is present but that's another subject).

A very good library for browsing PE files in python is [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile).

Here's an example to get the first 10 bytes at the program entry point:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os.path
import pefile


def find_entry_point_section(pe, eop_rva):
    for section in pe.sections:
        if section.contains_rva(eop_rva):
            return section

    return None


def main(file_path):
    print("Opening {}".format(file_path))

    try:
        pe = pefile.PE(file_path, fast_load=True)
        # AddressOfEntryPoint if guaranteed to be the first byte executed.
        eop = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint
        code_section = find_entry_point_section(pe, eop)
        if not code_section:
            return

        print("[+] Code section found at offset: "
              "{:#x} [size: {:#x}]".format(code_section.PointerToRawData,
                                          code_section.SizeOfRawData))

        # get first 10 bytes at entry point and dump them
        code_at_oep = code_section.get_data(eop, 10)
        print("[*] Code at EOP:\n{}".
              format(" ".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in code_at_oep)))

    except pefile.PEFormatError as pe_err:
        print("[-] error while parsing file {}:\n\t{}".format(file_path,
                                                              pe_err))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("[*] {} <PE_Filename>".format(sys.argv[0]))
    else:
        file_path = sys.argv[1]
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            main(file_path)
        else:
            print("[-] {} is not a file".format(file_path))
```

Simply pass the name of your PE file as the first argument.

In the above code the `code_at_oep` variable holds the first few bytes of the entry point. From there you can pass this bytes to the capstone engine.

Note that these first bytes might simply be a `jmp` or `call` instruction, so you'll have to follow the code execution in order to disassemble correctly. Disassembling correctly a program is still an open problem in computer science...

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what OS you're using. You have some other questions about Linux, so I'm assuming you're using that. On Linux, executables are typically in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format, so you'll need a [python library to read that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101272/library-to-read-elf-file-dwarf-debug-information) or else to use some other tool to extract the part of the ELF file that you want.

The actual instructions are stored in the `.text` section, so if you extract that section's contents, those should be the raw bytes you want to disassemble.

Comment: Thank you.  You answered the question I should have asked at the end of your response.  I'm working with PE files and you made it clear what I'm seeking is a dump of the .text section.  But, for the life of me I can't find the .text section amidst all the information that the pefile library outputs.

Comment: @AsaHunt Sorry, I'm not really familiar with pefile. I'm going to edit your question to try and attract some more-appropriate folks.

Answer (score 0):

so here is my code that disassembles your exe file and gives you an output in x86 assembly language I used [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile) and [capstone](https://www.capstone-engine.org/) library

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pefile
from capstone import *

# load the target PE file
pe = pefile.PE("/file/path/code.exe")

# get the address of the program entry point from the program header
entrypoint = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint

# compute memory address where the entry code will be loaded into memory
entrypoint_address = entrypoint+pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase

# get the binary code from the PE file object
binary_code = pe.get_memory_mapped_image()[entrypoint:entrypoint+100]

# initialize disassembler to disassemble 32 bit x86 binary code
disassembler = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_32)

# disassemble the code
for instruction in disassembler.disasm(binary_code, entrypoint_address):
    print("%s\t%s" %(instruction.mnemonic, instruction.op_str))
```

make sure to change and give the correct path of your exe file, also you need to specify how many instructions you want to print out at line number 15. here `[entrypoint:entrypoint+100]` I specify only 100 instructions but you can change it.

[image: here is the output of the code]