# How to get BACKTRACE (function + line number) on Solaris?

Tags: c, solaris, stack-trace, traceback, pstack

I have done some code in C that happily send the full backtrace with function name and line number to a log file.

This was done using a mixture of backtrace, backtrace_symbols and dladdr and ADDR2LINE on LINUX. Also using the "execinfo.h" on Linux....

So essentially the following:

Backtrace: Line Locations:

```
signalErrorHandler
/home/lynton/Desktop/TestThreadLeak/TestThreadLeak/./main.c:211
??
??:0
*__GI_raise
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/signal/../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
*__GI_abort
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/stdlib/abort.c:94
__libc_message
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/libio/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:168
malloc_printerr
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/malloc/malloc.c:6283
*__GI___libc_free
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/malloc/malloc.c:3739
threadMainLoop
/home/lynton/Desktop/TestThreadLeak/TestThreadLeak/./main.c:260
start_thread
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/nptl/pthread_create.c:304
??
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.12.1/misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:114
```

Now that I have taken the code to Solaris I see it is not supported ;-(

I have tried the pstack approach on Solaris and get something like:

```
15871:  ./exit_test
-----------------  lwp# 1 / thread# 1  --------------------
 ffffffff7efdaf48 lwp_wait (2, ffffffff7ffffb9c)
 ffffffff7efd34ac _thrp_join (2, 0, 0, 1, 0, ffffffff7ffffb9c) + 38
 00000001000012f0 main (1, ffffffff7ffffd28, ffffffff7ffffd38, 100101f68, 100000000, ffffffff7f500200) + 204
 0000000100000ba4 _start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 7c
-----------------  lwp# 2 / thread# 2  --------------------
 ffffffff7efdb210 waitid   (0, 3e01, ffffffff7eaf8c30, 3)
 ffffffff7efc9cbc waitpid (3e01, ffffffff7eaf8eb0, 0, 0, ffffffff7f100300, 0) + 64
 ffffffff7efbcc08 system (ffffffff7eaf9ff0, 1ad8, 1800, 0, ffffffff7f13c000, ffffffff7eaf8f18) + 394
 0000000100000fec signalErrorHandler (b, 0, ffffffff7eafbba0, 40000000, 0, 0) + 2bc
 ffffffff7efd6fdc __sighndlr (b, 0, ffffffff7eafbba0, 100000d30, 0, 0) + c
 ffffffff7efcab70 call_user_handler (ffffffff7f500a00, ffffffff7f500a00, ffffffff7eafbba0, 12, 0, 0) + 3e0
 ffffffff7efcad7c sigacthandler (0, 0, ffffffff7eafbba0, ffffffff7f500a00, 0, ffffffff7f13c000) + 68
 --- called from signal handler with signal 0 (SIGEXIT) ---
 ffffffff7ee0052c memcpy (ffffffff7ffffd28, 1fc000, 0, 0, 100001040, 0) + 30
 ffffffff7efd6eb0 _lwp_start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

How can I use the above somehow to PROGRAMATICALLY get the LINE NUMBERS and function names as well? I have see something about "walkcontext" or "walkstack"....does anyone have any sample code for me to get line numbers etc?

Also, I have used ADDR2LINE on Linux and it works great.....can someone tell me how to use it on Solaris from the DUMP above? I cannot get it to work ;-(

Any advise will be hugely appreciated

Thanks

Lynton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start out by saying that C might not be the best way to do this in 2011 (depending on what your larger aims are). Check out this other question: [Analizing MIPS binaries: is there a Python library for parsing binary data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954/python-libdwarf-module) which references (eg) [pydevtools](http://code.google.com/p/pydevtools/).

That said, please find below an example using `gaddr2line` (which is how Solaris spells `addr2line`).

This short program just calls function `foo()`, which in turn calls `pstack(1)` (on line 9, via `system(3C)`). In the output from the program, `pstack(1)` tells us that the address in function `foo()` when `system()` is invoked is 0x00010724. Finally, running `gaddr2line(1)` on that address tells us that this corresponds to line 9 of `foo.c`, and we have come full circle.

```
/tmp $ cat -n foo.c
     1  
     2  #include <stdio.h>
     3  #include <stdlib.h>
     4  #include <unistd.h>
     5  
     6  int foo() {
     7      char buf[64];
     8      snprintf(buf, 64, "/bin/pstack %i", getpid());
     9      return system(buf);
    10  }
    11  
    12  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    13      return foo();
    14  }
    15  
/tmp $ gcc -g -o foo foo.c
/tmp $ 
/tmp $ ./foo 
15954:  ./foo
 ff2cd4d8 waitid   (0, 3e53, ffbff668, 3)
 ff2bce94 waitpid  (3e53, ffbff7bc, 0, 0, ffbff814, ff390140) + 60
 ff2afe20 system   (ffbff910, ff339bd0, 20000, 1, ff3303d8, ffbff814) + 2ec
 00010724 foo      (209b8, 1c00, ff335900, 4, ff392a00, ff2b6d6c) + 38
 00010748 main     (1, ffbffa34, ffbffa3c, 209dc, ff3900c0, 0) + c
 00010584 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c
/tmp $ 
/tmp $ gaddr2line -e foo 00010724 
/tmp/foo.c:9
/tmp $
```

Following on from that, here is a short example of using `walkcontext(3C)` to walk the stack. To get debug line number information however you will need to query the appropriate sections of the ELF(?) binary using (eg) [libdwarf](http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html) in the `walker()` function but this should get you started.

```
/tmp $ cat -n bar.c
     1  
     2  #include <stdio.h>
     3  #include <stdlib.h>
     4  #include <unistd.h>
     5  #include <ucontext.h>
     6  #include <dlfcn.h>
     7  
     8  int walker(uintptr_t pc, int sig, void *usrarg) {
     9  
    10      Dl_info dlip;
    11  
    12      if(dladdr((void *)pc, &dlip)) {
    13          (void)printf(" %08lx %s %s\n", pc, dlip.dli_fname, dlip.dli_sname);
    14          return 0;
    15      } else {
    16          perror("dladdr()");
    17          return -1;
    18      }
    19  
    20  }
    21  
    22  int bar() {
    23  
    24      char buf[64];
    25      snprintf(buf, 64, "/bin/pstack %i", getpid());
    26      system(buf);
    27  
    28      (void)printf("\nprintstack()\n");
    29      printstack(0);
    30  
    31      ucontext_t ucp;
    32      if(getcontext(&ucp)) {
    33          perror("\ngetcontext()");
    34          return -1;
    35      } else {
    36          (void)printf("\nwalkcontext()\n");
    37          return walkcontext(&ucp, &walker, NULL);
    38      }
    39  
    40  }
    41  
    42  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    43      return bar();
    44  }
    45  
/tmp $ gcc -g -o bar bar.c
/tmp $
/tmp $ ./bar 
16486:  ./bar
 ff2cd4d8 waitid   (0, 4067, ffbff4b8, 3)
 ff2bce94 waitpid  (4067, ffbff60c, 0, 0, ffbff664, ff390140) + 60
 ff2afe20 system   (ffbff928, ff339bd0, 20000, 1, ff3303d8, ffbff664) + 2ec
 000108b8 bar      (20c70, 1c00, ff335900, 4, ff392a00, ff2b6d6c) + 38
 00010968 main     (1, ffbffa4c, ffbffa54, 20c94, ff3900c0, 0) + c
 00010698 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 5c

printstack()
/tmp/bar:bar+0x54
/tmp/bar:main+0xc
/tmp/bar:_start+0x5c

walkcontext()
 00010968 /tmp/bar main
 00010698 /tmp/bar _start
```